# Proper instance for "nested" matching

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a Lemma of the form `FnEquivInner f g` implies 
`outer t (bind t f) === outer t (bind t g)` (full example posted below).

I wish to understand what kind of `Proper` instance I need to write for `outer` that lets me perform a `rewrite` in this case, to replace `f` with `g` in the call of `outer`.

In general, how does one write `Proper` instances where the patterns are non-trivial?

```
Require Import Setoid.
Require Import Morphisms.

Section PROPERINSTANCE.

  Variable T: Type.
  Variable inner:  T -> (T -> T) -> T.
  Variable outer : T -> (T -> T)  -> T.
  Variable bind: T -> (T -> T) -> (T -> T).

  Variable equiv: T -> T -> Prop.
  Infix "===" := equiv (at level 50).

  Variable equivalence_equiv: Equivalence equiv.

  (** Check that equivalence can be found by Coq *)
  Lemma check_equiv_refl: forall (t: T), t === t.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Definition FnEquivInner (f g: T -> T): Prop := forall (t: T),
      inner t f === inner t g.

  (** This is a part of my theory *)
  Variable FnEquivOuter:
    forall (f g: T -> T)
      (t t1: T)
      (EQUIVINNER: FnEquivInner f g),
      outer t1 (bind t f) === outer t1 (bind t g).

  (** This is not a made up example to push coq, I have an actual theorem like this:
   * https://github.com/bollu/vellvm/blob/master/src/coq/Memory.v#L923
     inner = memEffect
     outer = memD
     bind = bindM
   *)


  Lemma useFnEquivOuter:
    forall (f g: T -> T)
      (t: T)
      (EQUIVINNER: FnEquivInner f g),
      outer t (bind t f) === outer t (bind t g).
  Proof.
    intros.
    (** What should the Proper instance look like so that if I have a FnEquivInner witness,
  I can `rewrite` using it? *)
    setoid_rewrite EQUIVINNER.
  Qed.

End PROPERINSTANCE.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `Set Typeclasses Debug.` and then `try setoid_rewrite EQUIVINNER`, and look for the lines that include `looking for` which come immediately before lines that mention `proper_subrelation`, you will see

```
Debug: 1.1-1: looking for (Proper (?R ==> FnEquivInner ==> ?r) bind) with backtracking
Debug: 1.1-1.2-2.1-1: looking for (Proper (?R --> FnEquivInner --> Basics.flip ?r) bind) with backtracking
Debug: 1.3-2.1-1: looking for (Proper (FnEquivInner --> Basics.flip ?r) (bind t)) with backtracking
```

This is basically a list of the `Proper` instances you can add to make typeclass resolution for `setoid_rewrite` go through.

For example, if I write

```
Global Instance: Proper (eq ==> FnEquivInner ==> eq) bind. Admitted.
```

then `setoid_rewrite` goes through.

I assume, though, that you will want something like

```
Global Instance bind_Proper : Proper (eq ==> FnEquivInner ==> FnEquivInner) bind. Admitted.
```

If I write this, then `setoid_rewrite` fails.  Let's dig through the typeclass log again, this time looking for where resolution goes wrong after applying `bind_Proper`.  Following the same rule as above, we see that the first line matching the above criterion is

```
Debug: 2.1-1: looking for (Proper (?R ==> FnEquivInner ==> ?r) outer) with backtracking
```

If I add

```
Global Instance outer_Proper: Proper (eq ==> FnEquivInner ==> equiv) outer. Admitted.
```

then `setoid_rewrite` again goes through.

Note that you get to fill in `?`-prefixed relations (`?R`, `?r`, etc) with any reflexive relation you'd like.

---

You may ask "why does this black magic work?"  The answer is that `proper_subrelation` is where Coq generally goes wrong.  It means, roughly, "I have nothing in my database matching what you're looking for; let me blindly try everything in my database and see if any of them are maybe close enough to work."*  (Where "close enough" means "is a subrelation of".)  So we look for the places where Coq goes wrong in its search, and we look immediately before that to see what it was looking at.  (There are often many steps of `partial_application_tactic`, which strips arguments off of functions; this is why you only need one `Proper` instance for `bind`, rather than one for `bind t` and another for `fun t => bind t f`.)

*This is actually useful, sometimes, because `eq` is a subrelation of every reflexive relation, and so you can get away with not entering relations when you can just use `eq`.  But most of the time, `proper_subrelation` is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, which is in the spirit of "teach a man to fish". I never realised that I can use typeclass debugging to understand the resolution of `Proper` instances, though in hindsight it seems obvious :)